# How do you use Devise helper methods so that certain controller actions are restricted to a certain user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Currently building an education app and I have an admin model and a user model.

I simply only want an admin to have access to links that lead to create, edit and delete requests.

I am currently using an `<% if user_signed_in? %>` to allow only signed-in users to be able to access the link but since I've added an admin role, I only want the admin to be able to access the links.

I havn't done anything else to my admin or user controller, just generated the necessary models and controllers.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170714091732) do

  create_table "admins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admins_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admins_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "lessons", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "course_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Comment: Do you have some role in users table as admin?

Comment: No I do not. I chose the path of creating two user models, one being an admin and the other being a user, so I don't have any database table columns that indicate any user roles.

Comment: Do you have any associations between those models?

Comment: No associations. All I've done so far is to generate two models and its corresponding controller.

Comment: Please show your database schema.

Comment: Then how you are able to login for a admin? Do you devise set up for Admin model too?

Comment: I am able to login as an admin by using Devise and going through the admin/sign-in path. @spickermann I've added my database schema onto the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up devise for Admin model properly you should be able to add before filter to your controller actions like this: `before_action: authenticate_admin!`
You also should have access to other helpers like `admin_signed_in?`